# HTML CSS scroll horizontal

Tags: html, css

I want to make a scroll horizontal when there's to many of `article` , not make them jump down. So I want it to be able to scroll so you can see the rest. but it doesn't work.

Snippet:

```css
#latest {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 150px
}
article {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div id="latest">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about it? Can you make an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us?

Comment: The #latest doesn't list the article with a scroll horizontaly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your articles `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` and set wrapper to be `white-space:nowrap` like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/andyfurniss/tobrbf7q/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#latest{
background: #eee;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 150px
}

#wrapper {
white-space:nowrap;
}

article{
width: 250px;
height: 150px;
background: #ccc;
margin-right: 30px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="latest">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from @Andy Fumiss' answer, I integrated it some improvement:

**`display:inline-block` has a little drawback because empty spaces due to code indentation has effect like space characters.**

To show this effect, I [slightly edit his example](http://jsfiddle.net/tobrbf7q/1/) reducing margin-right separation to only `5px` and avoiding indentantion in html code of first two `article` tags.

As you can see, first margin is lesser than following, because from second one, there is *5px + empty space*.

**To avoid this undesired behaviour, you can set `font-size:0` on container and then restore its original value on content**, like in [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/tobrbf7q/2/)

Here, relevant portion of changed code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="latest">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <article></article><article></article>
        <article></article>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper {
    ...
    font-size:0;
}

article {
    ...
    font-size:13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:inline-block with white-space:nowrap

```
#latest {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 height: 80px;
 white-space:nowrap
}
article{
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
margin: 2px;
max-height: 150px;
cursor: pointer;
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;/* For IE7*/
*zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
vertical-align:top;
```

}